# Set a default document directory for Libre Office Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

How can I set a default document directory for Libre Office Calc?  For Libre Office Writer? ... etc.

Comment: Do you want to set **different** default document directory for the different applications, or one for all together?

Comment: I want to make a directory structure like this: --Libre Office, - Calc - Writer - etc... And be able to put documents by default into each subdirectory. Failing in that, just being able to specify a single default directory would be about half an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default documents path using the Options dialog. Open menu "`Tools`" -> "`Options`" -> "`General`" -> "`Paths`" and modify the "`My Documents`" path as requqired:

[image]

(Screenshot from [LibreOffice Wiki](http://wiki.documentfoundation.org/File:Screenshot-Options_-_LibreOffice_-_Paths.png))

This will set the documents path all LibreOffice applications, so you can't set differrent paths for Writer, Calc and so on. If this is important for you, you could create a macro that opens the "`Save as...`" dialog and sets the path automatically.